# comment-kill for entire region

Tags: comment, kill-ring

Is there a similar command to [`comment-kill`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Comment-Commands.html) that kills all comments in a given region and saves them to the kill ring?

Comment: You can narrow to region, put point at the beginning of the region, and call `comment-kill` with a large numeric prefix-arg. Pitingly that does not concatenate all kills. You can reach that with the following advice (caution: hacky!): `(defun comment-kill-ad (fun &rest args) (kill-new "") (let ((last-command 'kill-region)) (apply fun args))) (advice-add 'comment-kill :around 'comment-kill-ad)`

Comment: Presumably you don't just want to kill the region or copy it to the kill-ring. Instead, you want to kill only the comments in the region. 
Do you want them *concatenated* in the kill-ring, as one ring entry? Or do you want each comment to be a separate kill-ring entry. The question could be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
   (defun ar-kill-comment-atpt ()
      "Deletes comment at point if any. "
      (interactive "*")
      (ar-th-kill 'comment))
```

Requires stuff from https://github.com/andreas-roehler/thingatpt-utils-core providing the `ar-th-kill` basics.

Deletes all comments at point. Narrow to region before in order to restrict.